# What fuel sources will my turtle accept?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

What fuel sources do turtles accept?  It seems that they used to accept more sources than they do now, and by now I mean any of the 1.5.2 mods, and by before I mean pre-1.5.2 mods.

Comment: Pray to god that PETA doesn't read this title

Comment: this could probably be figured out by a quick wikia search

Comment: anything that burns in a furnace will/should work

Comment: The wiki is not accurate at this time as the new packs have only recently been released and many (most if not all) of the changes are not updated.

Comment: @ratchetfreak used to be other things worked too, like batteries and energy crystals, and lets not forget charge stations. I want a comprehensive description of all things that work as of the current version, and perhaps bonus points for all things that used to work and no longer work\ or used to **NOT** work and now **DO**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question ended up intriguing me and so here's the results of my testing for 1.5.2

*Note: all testing was done in the FTB Unleashed modpack, I make no guarantees that gregtech or similar mods won't change any of this if they are used*

**Usable Liquid fuels**

- Any liquid that can be used as a fuel source for an engine or generator, except for buildcraft oil and fuel, and dartcraft force.
- lava will only work if provided in either buckets or cells, all other liquids seem to work in any container

**Usable Solid fuels**

- anything that can be burned in a furnace or a generator
- uranium ore, refined uranium, and all cells excluding near-depleted and re-enriched (only if an RTG module is fitted and the refuel is done by calling the refuel method on the peripheral directly from lua)

**Usable blocks and items**

- turtle charge stations

**Unusable sources**

- energy crystals, lapotronic crystals, and other similar EU storage
- buildcraft oil and fuel (as mentioned above)
- dartcraft force (also as mentioned above)

Comment: uranium ore works!?!? how much do you get for it

Comment: Uranium ore / refined uranium / uranium cell all provide 1000000 fuel units at a rate of 1 unit per 50 ticks. Double and quad cells provide 2x and 4x the amount of fuel, as expected.